# Integrating cvBlobslib with opencv2.3.1

Tags: opencv, blob

Installing `cvblobslib` gives an error "`"cxtypes.h"` not found". Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to types_c.h and include the folder in the include files under tools>>option. Hope it helps.